# Update database on android sqlite problems

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to update a row in my database but my code is not working, it changes nothing. Is there something missing in the code?

```
    public boolean updateContact(Contact contact) {
        db = getWritableDatabase();
```

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PHONE, contact.getPhone());
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, contact.getEmail());
    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, contact.getAddress());
    values.put(KEY_IMAGEURI, contact.getImageUri().toString());

    return (db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { "" + contact.getId() }) > 0);
    }
```

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

`private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactManager",
                            TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts",
                            KEY_ID = "id",
                            KEY_NAME = "name",
                            KEY_PHONE = "phone",
                            KEY_EMAIL = "email",
                            KEY_ADDRESS = "address",
                            KEY_IMAGEURI = "imageUri";

private static SQLiteDatabase db;

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," +
                KEY_PHONE + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT," + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT," + KEY_IMAGEURI + " TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
    onCreate(db);
}`

I was not able to solve this so to my aplication works I used another form to update my database, dropping it and creating another with the new values. But my first question still remains, why the update method was not working?

Comment: Show the table definition.

Comment: why don't you try replacing the item that you want to change and keep the one that you want to be there